# Синхронизация данных между PostgreSQL и MS SQL

Tags: postgresql

- БД на Postgresql 9.6 Ubuntu 16.04.
- БД на Ms sql, где данные обновляются каждые 5 минут.

Обе БД находится в одной сети.

Нужно что бы postgresql получал данные из MS sql каждые 5 минут.

На Postgresql поставил расширения: Pg_cron, pgagent, plpgsql, tds_fdw.

Как можно реализовать подобное решение?

Comment: А не разумнее наоборот? MS SQL ведь точно знает, когда (ну или что) данные изменились - и может сразу передать изменения в Postgresql, тогда как если запрашивает Postgres, будут как "зазоры" (данные "там" уже другие, а "тут" ещё старые), так и "холостые" обращения.

Comment: можно oracle golden gate использовать, он бесплатный, позволяет синхронизировать изменения между практически любыми СУБД в почти реальном времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используем 2 расширения oracle_fdw и tds-fdw(перед этим нужно установить ODBC и Freetds) настраиваем внешние таблицы, устанавливаем pgagent делаем запросы updaet или insert в зависимости что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

рекомендую воспользоваться технологией:
[http://olontsev.ru/2012/10/introducing-change-tracking/](http://Change%20Tracking)
Это позволяет узнать что именно изменилось в БД MS SQL от предыдущего такого же запроса.